# failed push to heroku using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i try to deploy my rails app to heroku, but when `git push heroku master` i get error like this :

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg
       * carrierwave
       * debugger
       * rails_12factor
       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg
       * carrierwave
       * debugger
       * rails_12factor
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

why i get error like this? i already to try `bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment` and run `git push heroku master` again but i still get same error like before???

i'm using ruby 2.0 and rails 4, please tell me if i'm wrong? thanks before

**Edit:**

my gemfile:

```
source 'rubygems.org'; 
gem 'rails', '4.0.1' 
group :development do 
  gem 'sqlite3' 
end 
group :production do 
  gem 'pg' 
end 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' 
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'turbolinks' 
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2' 
group :doc do 
  gem 'sdoc', require: false 
end 
gem 'devise' 
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" 
gem 'carrierwave' 
gem 'debugger', 
group: [:development, :test] gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Comment: could you show us what your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` look like in the repository? I am assuming that you've checked in your `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: my gemfile : source 'https://rubygems.org' gem 'rails', '4.0.1' group :development do gem 'sqlite3' end group :production do gem 'pg' end gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0' gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' gem 'jquery-rails' gem 'turbolinks' gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2' group :doc do gem 'sdoc', require: false end gem 'devise' gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" gem 'carrierwave' gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test] gem 'rails_12factor'

Comment: I've moved your gemfile source to the question. Please do not post code in comment, makes it very difficult to read. Now, have you checked in your `Gemfile.lock` in your repository? Could you edit the question with it's source?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete `Gemfile.lock` file then commit and push to heroku again.